# Can't add new row to table

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, appendchild

```
function load(){
    var row="<tr><td><select id=\"chooseclass\"><option value=\"math\">Math</option><option value=\"phys\">Physics</option><option value=\"lit\">Literature</option><option value=\"chem\">Chemistry</option><option value=\"bio\">Biology</option><option value=\"lang\">Language</option><option value=\"proj\">Project</option><option value=\"elec\">Elective</option></select></td><td><input id=\"choosemods\" type=\"text\" /></td><td><input id=\"choosegrade\" type=\"text\" /></td></tr>";
    var tablebody = document.getElementById("classestable");
    tablebody.innerHTML += "<tbody></tbody>";
    tablebody.getElementsByTagName("tbody").innerHTML = "";
    for(var i=0;i<15;i++){
        tablebody.getElementsByTagName("tbody").innerHTML += row;
    }
}
```

The code above runs fine except the contents of `row` does not get added to `tbody`.

`console.log` shows that the contents of `row` is valid html and there are no errors in the console. Why is that not being added?

Comment: Instead of `tablebody.getElementsByTagName("tbody")`, use `tablebody.tBodies[0]`

Comment: And using `.innerHTML` for elements is hard to manage...look into `insertRow`, `insertCell`, `createElement`, and `appendChild`

Comment: And you shouldn't be putting the same row in 15 times - there are elements in there with the same `id` attribute, which is not allowed with HTML. Well, at least you'll have a difficult manipulating each of them with Javascript...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getElementsByTagName  returns a NodeList and you access it the first node using the index of the node

I would change the code to the following

```
var innerRow = "";

for(var i=0;i<15;i++){
    innerRow += row;
}

tablebody.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].innerHTML = innerRow
```

this way you only scanning the DOM once not 15 times

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `innerHTML` on tables in Internet Explorer, `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList` rather than a single node, and besides tables have a `tBodies` property.

Your revised code should be:

```
function load(){
  var tr = document.createElement('tr'), td;
  td = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
  td.innerHTML = "<select id=\"chooseclass\"><option value=\"math\">Math</option><option value=\"phys\">Physics</option><option value=\"lit\">Literature</option><option value=\"chem\">Chemistry</option><option value=\"bio\">Biology</option><option value=\"lang\">Language</option><option value=\"proj\">Project</option><option value=\"elec\">Elective</option></select>";
  td = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
  td.innerHTML = "<input id=\"choosemods\" type=\"text\" />";
  td = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
  td.innerHTML = "<input id=\"choosegrade\" type=\"text\" />";
  var tablebody = document.getElementById("classestable").tBodies[0];
  for(var i=0;i<15;i++){
      tablebody.appendChild(tr.cloneNode(true));
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating and appending a `tbody` that already implicitly exists?

Comment: Because I'm not thinking straight XD

Comment: Haha no problem, just wondering. Another question - what's the `tr.cloneNode(true)` for? Why not just append `tr`? This one I don't know the answer to

Comment: If you just append the same `tr` 15 times, you still only have one row. `cloneNode` is to create  15 copies of the row and append them.

Comment: I'm an idiot - I guess I didn't even look at what the original code was attempting to do. I didn't realize the OP was putting 15 copies in. I remembered the loop of 15, but I guess I thought they were making 15 different rows based on `i` or something. Maybe I should read it. Your `cloneNode` makes sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a query selector instead of `getElementsByTagName`.

```
document.querySelector('#classettable tbody').innerHTML += row;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point adding to dom each time the loop runs. Add it to an html variable and do one dom transaction.

```
function load(){
    var html= '';
    var row="<tr><td><select id=\"chooseclass\"><option value=\"math\">Math</option><option value=\"phys\">Physics</option><option value=\"lit\">Literature</option><option value=\"chem\">Chemistry</option><option value=\"bio\">Biology</option><option value=\"lang\">Language</option><option value=\"proj\">Project</option><option value=\"elec\">Elective</option></select></td><td><input id=\"choosemods\" type=\"text\" /></td><td><input id=\"choosegrade\" type=\"text\" /></td></tr>";
    var tablebody = document.getElementById("classestable");
    tablebody.innerHTML += "<tbody></tbody>";
    tablebody.getElementsByTagName("tbody").innerHTML = "";
    for(var i=0;i<15;i++){
        html += row;
    }
    tablebody.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].innerHTML = html;// Select first element from array of nodes
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't address the fact that IE doesn't allow `innerHTML` inside a `<table>` element.